# How to read excel data only after a string is found but without using skiprows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis, data-manipulation

[image]

I want to read the data after the string "Executed Trade". I want to do that **dynamically**. Not using "skiprows". I know openpyxl can be an option. But I am still struggling to do so. Could you guys please help me with that thing cause I have many files like the one is shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

**Try**:

```
import pandas as pd

#change the Excel filename and the two mentions of 'col1' for whatever the column is
df = pd.read_excel('dictatorem.xlsx')
df = df.iloc[df.col1[df.col1 == 'Executed Trades'].index.tolist()[0]+1:]
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

**Example input/output:**

[image]